# How to handle multiple spinner selected item comparison?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I am trying to get my app to display either a text or an image when two spinners selected values equal each other.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner sp1 =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        String txtFromSpinner1 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Spinner sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp2);
        String txtFromSpinner2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (txtFromSpinner1.equals(1)&& txtFromSpinner2.equals(2)){

            TextView textElement = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txResult);
            textElement.setText("3");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting a string and checking with an int. Check your condition.

Comment: Also your condition will only be evaluated once when the activity loads and not when user changes the `Spinner` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Spinner sp1 =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
Spinner sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp2);
TextView textElement = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txResult);              
Button showResult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowResult);

showResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String txtFromSpinner1 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String txtFromSpinner2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

         if (txtFromSpinner1.equals("1")&& txtFromSpinner2.equals("2"))
                textElement.setText("3");


        }
    });
```

Comment: When I input your code, I do not get any errors but I do not get anything to show in my textview. Should I make a button for the user to press for this to display results?

Comment: But only if you need a button to show the text. Otherwise you have to handle this inside your Spinner's `onItemSelected()` method if you want to do this dynamically

Comment: Awesome, this works. Thank you very much. I just had to make the first 3 lines of code "final" and everything worked. So in theory, I could get the spinners to equal an image instead if I wanted to by just adding in an imageview?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Please explain

Comment: if I wanted the spinners to display an image, I could add an ImageView to the whole thing, right?

Comment: Yes you can do that in your spinner item xml

Answer (score 0):

For comparing the two spinners selected values, you should use

```
String spinnerOne = mySpinnerOne.getSelectedItem().toString() ;
String spinnerTwo = mySpinnerTwo.getSelectedItem().toString() ;
```

Since `spinnerOne` and `spinnerTwo` are both `java strings`, you should use the equals method to compare them.

```
if(spinnerOne.equals(spinnerTwo))
```

Finally, for handling the changes in the spinners selection, every time the user selects a new value, you should use `onItemSelectedListener()` :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: So do I need to get ride of what code I have and add yours? I am sorry but this is confusing for me and I know that I that this is probably something simple.

Comment: Yes. replace your if for comparing the selected items with mine, and add onItemSelectedListener to both spinners and write the code for comparing selected values, in the "onItemSelected" method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have got everything to work now.

Answer (score 0):

`txtFromSpinner1.equals(1)` is not going to work because you are comparing a string against a number and that will return false,

you need instead to compare the strings of the spinners.

...

```
txtFromSpinner1.equals(txtFromSpinner2)
```

OR using quotes in your literals

```
if (txtFromSpinner1.equals("1")&& txtFromSpinner2.equals("2")){
```